# Signal code: Address not mapped (1) how should I define a variable dynamically to avoid it?

Tags: c, mpi

I have the following code - it is an image filter, but in this case I am not using the convolution part - which fails with the error from the title, when using scatter. I think that the error is in the receiver buffer, but can not figure out why:

```c
#include "utils.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef char pixel_t[3];

typedef struct image_s {
    pixel_t *data_in, 
            *data_out;
    size_t   width, height;
} image_t;

#define DIE_MPI(msg) do {                       \
fprintf(stderr, "FAILURE: %s\n", msg);  \
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                     \
} while(0)

char *g_progname;
static inline void usage(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s [filename [x y]]\n", g_progname);
    exit(0);
}

void img_load(const char* filename, const size_t width, const size_t height, image_t* img)
{
    FILE* fsrc = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fsrc) 
        FATAL("fopen");

    fseek(fsrc, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t sz = ftell(fsrc);
    fseek(fsrc, 0, SEEK_SET);

    img->data_in  = XMALLOC(sz);
    img->data_out = XMALLOC(sz);
    img->width    = width;
    img->height   = height;

    memset(img->data_in,  0UL, sz);
    memset(img->data_out, 0UL, sz);

    size_t n_bytes = fread(img->data_in, 1, sz, fsrc);
    printf("Read %u. Expected %u bytes\n", n_bytes, sz);
    if (n_bytes < sz) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read fewer bytes than expected: %u/%u\n", n_bytes, sz);
    }

    if (feof(fsrc)) {
        printf("Finished reading %s\n", filename);
        clearerr(fsrc);
    }

    fclose(fsrc);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int err = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    if (err) DIE_MPI("MPI_Init");

    int size = 0;
    err = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if (err) DIE_MPI("MPI_Comm_size");

    int rank = 0;
    err = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (err) DIE_MPI("MPI_Comm_rank");

    uint32_t X        = 512, 
             Y        = 512;
    char*    filename = NULL;
    g_progname        = argv[0]; 
    switch(argc) {
        case 4:
                X        = strtoul(argv[3], NULL, 0);
                Y        = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
        case 2:
                filename = argv[1];
                break;
        case 1:
                filename = "lena_color.data";
                X        = 512;
                Y        = 512;
                break;
        default:
                usage();
    }
    
    pixel_t *bitmap_in;
    bitmap_in = malloc(X * Y * sizeof(pixel_t));
    image_t img;
    if(rank==0)
    {
        printf("Processing %s...\n", filename);
        img_load(filename, X, Y, &img);
    }
    
    MPI_Scatter(img, X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t), MPI_CHAR, bitmap_in, X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    err = MPI_Finalize();
    if (err) DIE("MPI_Finalize");
    
    return err;
    }
```

To sum up the problem, I have a mapping trouble with either the sending buffer or the receiving buffer. I have tried adding more space to the memory allocated on the receiving buffer but it did not solved it. Another cause could be that I am sending more memory than the allocated in the structure image_t, but I do not think so, because it should be twice as big as the size that I am trying to send.

Perhaps I am missing something with my conclusions, as I am still learning c and MPI.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see where the error occurs?

Comment: I mean, I commented the scatter, and the error "dissapears", so the problem is on this command. But the debugger for MPI of the raspberry pi is not that specific

Comment: `img` seems to be `image_t`, which has data with pointers in it, but you're sending it seemingly like it's raw pixel data. It seems to me (knowing nothing about how those types are used) that you'd want to send `img->data_in` (and maybe receive to `img->data_out`). Another thing that seems odd is that you allocate `X * Y * sizeof(pixel_t)`, but then send/receive `X*Y/sizeof(pixel_t)`.

Comment: you cannot use `MPI_CHAR` to scatter `img`. instead, you should indidually scatter `img.data_in` and `img.data_out` and set `width` and `height` accordingly on the non root ranks.

Comment: @ThomasJager I think that the sizes are okay, I allocate `X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t)` in order to have a matrix of `[X][Y][3]` allocated all contiguous. Then, when I call img_load, I fill the structure image_t with the data of an image. Then, I send `X*Y/sizeof(pixel_t)` because it is how many "elements" does my function have (as you know it has a value of char[3] but I am sending char, so this division must be made in order to calculate the elements).

Comment: @EnzoBasile The number of elements would be just `X * Y`. Since you're sending as characters, you need the total size, which is `X * Y * sizeof(pixel_t)`. The number of characters to send is the same as the number of characters allocated. The rest also still applies, you're sending a struct that points to data (but does not contain it) when it seems like you want to send raw data.

Comment: @ThomasJager so I changed the code to  `MPI_Scatter(&img.data_in, X*Y, MPI_CHAR, &bitmap_in, X*Y, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` but still getting the problem of the address not maped (1). So it is still being sent more elements than the ones that I keep in the memory

Comment: Have you done what I initially suggested and used a debugger to identify where the error occurs?

Comment: At the very least, you should `MPI_Scatter(img.data_in, ..., bitmap_in, ...)`

Comment: @ThomasJager Hi, sorry for the late response, I just came home an hour ago, yes, I tried what you initially said, but still getting the mapping error. About the debugger, it is not possible to add more libraries or things because I have been told to not touch the things inside the Raspberry. So the teacher supposes me to acknowledge by hand, the thing is that the error is quite simple, I am sending the wrong amount of data, but can not figure out why, because I am pretty sure that is the correct one

Comment: @ThomasJager Maybe last time I was not so clear, but just to make sure I will write this again. Last time I tried what you suggested (changing img for img.data_in and then sending X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t) and many variants). Eventhough, I am sure that the correct size should be X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t)/sizeof(char), Why? Well, because I need to send a quantity of elements, and as I am sending char, I have to convert from pixel_t to char the size (therefore, the result should be X*Y*3).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Another mistake that you told me last time was sending pointer, but it is supposed for MPI to get the memory that allocates the pointer, for example, if xptr points to x, then MPI will send x (not the place where x is in the memory). Eventhough, I have tried to send img.data_in withouth the &. I will leave the final attempt:
MPI_Scatter(img.data_in, X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t)/sizeof(char), MPI_CHAR, &bitmap_in, `X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t)/sizeof(char), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

Comment: @EnzoBasile `sizeof(char)` is *by definition* 1. `sizeof` tells you how big an object/type is in number of `char`, so `X * Y * sizeof(pixel_t)` tells you how large your object is in `char`. What you say in your comment doesn't match the code, where you divide by `sizeof(pixel_t)`, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: The receive buffer should be bitmap_in without &.

Comment: @ThomasJager cheeses, I left the wrong one, I actually did X*Y*sizeof(pixel_t) -I also divided by sizeof(char) but =1 so does not matter- I am editing the code rn

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet As you said, the error was there (also in the size of the arrays, but the biggest part was there). Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not in the definition of the variable itself, but in the call to the variable in the MPI_Scatter(), there is no need to put "&var" in the MPI_Scatter(), you should just put "var"